# Atom + Git: unable to push after changing to 2FA / PAT

Tags: git, atom-editor

starting from today, I am no longer able to push my commits using the git plugin in atom. The error message:

```
remote: Password authentication is temporarily disabled as part of a brownout. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/....my_repo....': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I already have set up 2FA for normal logins and created an personal access token as requested in the error message. However, I'm not clear on where to store this new information. Any help on how to fix this is be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Additional information:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Atom    : 1.54.0
- Electron: 6.1.12
- Chrome  :
  76.0.3809.146
- Node    : 12.4.0
- git: git version 2.25.1

Answer (score 3):

So I figured this out I think:
Atom uses the stored credentials from git directly, no specific config file on atoms side.

To solve my problem, I changed the remote url to ssh (I had ssh keys setup) and atom immediately worked again.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:dluecking/my_repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub does not support repo actions using a user/pass login since August 13, 2021. I have now setup SSH connectivity instead running through the following commands:

**1. Change link in your repo**

`git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:repo-owner-here/repo-name-here.git`

**2. Generate a new SSH key & add it to the ssh-agent (MacOS)**

[see relevant GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key)

**3. Add SSH public Key to GitHub user account**

[see relevant GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

**4. Test & Connect**

`ssh -T git@github.com`

which likely returns a warning, type

`yes`

which should return

"Hi your-username-here! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."